# Cómo mover la imagen de la tortuga en un array 20x20 dentro de un canvas

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo un programa que simule los graficos de tortuga, tengo como limite un array de 20x20 el cual se tiene que llamar piso. El problema que tengo es cómo hacer que la tortuga que está en el canvas se mueva con los comandos pero con ayuda de los botones, es decir que cuando pulse el botón 1, realice la acción que dice abajo. Agradecería su ayuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Graficos Tortuga</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var piso = new array[20][20];
    var centinela = 0;
    var avanze = 0;
    var filaActiva = 0;
    var columnaActiva = 0;
    var estado = {left, right};
    var pluma = {up, down};
    </script>  
</head>
<body>

<center><h1>Gráficos Tortuga</h1> 

<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" style="border: 2px solid #000000"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imagen = new Image();
    imagen.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/25/01/13/turtle-41565_960_720.png";
    imagen.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(imagen,0,0,30,30);
    }
</script> 


<br><br>
<label>Introduzca el comando a utilizar: 
<input type="button" onclick="showme('1')" value="1"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showme('2')" value="2"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showme('3')" value="3"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showme('4')" value="4"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showme('5')" value="5"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showme('6')" value="6"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showme('9')" value="9"/>
</center>


<h3>Estos son los comandos a utilizar: </h3>
<h4>
(1): Pluma arriba<br>
(2): Pluma abajo<br>
(3): Girar a la derecha<br>
(4): Girar a la izquierda<br>
(5,e): Avanzar (e) espacios.<br>
(6): Imprimir el arreglo de 20 por 20<br>
(9): Fin de datos (centinela)<br></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por otro lado, te invito a realizar un [tour] para que ganes tu primera medalla y consultar [¿cómo elaborar una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También, considere consultar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Esto aumentará las posibilidades de conseguir una buena respuesta.

Comment: Hola @Ricardo, ¿podrías colocar el código de tu función (`showme()`)? Además, en la línea `var piso = new array[20][20];` se hace referencia a un array que no existe y por otro lado, la palabra reservada **new** se utiliza para los constructores. En tal caso, si lo que deseas es crear un `arrray` denominada piso deberías definirla así: `var piso = new Array(20, 20);` a menos que la primera sea un **Array** de dos dimensiones de la que se tiene claro su contenido.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. no entiendo a qué te refieres con colocar el código de esa función. Soy algo nuevo y me pusieron este programa que para mi es complejo. Y la verdad no encuentro mucho acerca de esto en google.

Comment: Es decir, desde uno de los botones estás llamando a la función `showme()`, es decir, una función que no se encuentra definida en el código que has compartido acá.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Lo que creo que hace, es que mostrara el #1 o #2 etc, en el botón. Y con ello poder ingresar el comando que seleccione. Sé que estoy mal, no sé mucho y me gustaría que me resolvieras dudas.

Comment: Estuve realizando pruebas con tu código y me encontré con los detalles que te he mencionado. Se necesita saber qué debe hacer la función, de allí, la importancia de incorporarlo en tu pregunta. Es complicado entender qué es lo que desea hacer sin los detalles mencionados en estos comentarios.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. tienes algun otro medio para comunicarme contigo?

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. basicamente, lo que quiero hacer es: ingresar alguno de los comandos mencionados y que por ejemplo, si ingreso el 4 (girar a la izquierda) la imagen gire a la izq, y así. Lo que no logro hacer es cómo hacerlo con ayuda de botones o ingresando el comando. Y tampoco sé como moverlo en el canvas pero como si fuera un plano cartesiano, respetando el array de 20x20